# CGRectIntersectsRect not working how I would like

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cgrect

Thanks for taking the time to look at my noob question and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Firstly I am trying to make an object 'bounce' from one side of the screen to the other using bezier curves (don't want to use box2d).

The object has 4 states representing the 4 movements, when the object hits (reacts to) the floor it moves from the previous state to a new state, please see picture below...

[image]

**My problem is that I can not get it to transition from state 1 to state 4 using CGRect correctly. I can currently get the object to move states but then one of two things happen..

1) The below code will allow the object to change from state 1 to state 2 correctly but it will then not react with the floor (it just moves through it) at the end of state 2 so does not change to state 3.

```
 -(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime:(ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray *)listOfGameObjects {


    [self setDebugLabelTextAndPosition];


    if ([self isOutsideOfScreen])
        return;

   CGPoint currentSpitePosition = [self position];

    floorCharacter = (GameCharacter*)[[self parent]
                                       getChildByTag:kfloorSpriteTagValue];

    CGRect floorBoudingBox = [floorCharacter adjustedBoundingBox];
    CGRect ballBoundingBox = [self adjustedBoundingBox];

    CGRect characterBox = [character adjustedBoundingBox];
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(floorBoudingBox, ballBoundingBox)) {

        if (characterState == kStateTravelling) {
            [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint2];
        }

        if (characterState == kStateTravellingPoint2) {
            [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint3];

        }

    }
```

2) The below code will stop the object when it first hits the floor but if I remove the floor for a second while the program is running the object will then move to state 3 and once again stop when it hits the floor, if I remove the floor again it will once again move to state 4, this is without adding the other states (as you will see below) so it is just repeating state 2 each time. This I am guessing is because it returns TRUE as soon as it hits the floor and while it is TRUE it will not action.

```
-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime:(ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray *)listOfGameObjects {

    [self setDebugLabelTextAndPosition];

    if ([self isOutsideOfScreen])
        return;

   CGPoint currentSpitePosition = [self position];
   floorCharacter = (GameCharacter*)[[self parent]
                                       getChildByTag:kfloorSpriteTagValue];

    CGRect floorBoudingBox = [floorCharacter adjustedBoundingBox];
    CGRect ballBoundingBox = [self adjustedBoundingBox];

    isfloorWithinBoundingBox =
    CGRectIntersectsRect(floorBoudingBox, ballBoundingBox) ?
    YES : NO;

    if (isfloorWithinBoundingBox) {

        [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint2];

    }
```

What I want it to do is move between the 4 states if the floor is active in a 'bounce' movement, so as soon as state 1 is complete it will hit the floor and move into state 2 until it completes the curve movement and hits the floor again and then moves into state 3 etc.

---

Right I have got the above to work but do not completely understand how I have done it!

I tried using screenSize to determine where the object was and base my CGRect from that but it did not work at first. I then kept the code but added 'CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;' to the method and then to object performed just how I wanted.

I now however have the following errors when I use screenSize..
'Local declaration of 'screenSize' hide instance variable'

**What I would like to know is why its not working using screenSize until I declare it in the method (as its already been declared in another class that is imported into this one).**

Thanks again to anyone that has taken the time to read this.

my code is below...

```
-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime:(ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray *)listOfGameObjects {

    [self setDebugLabelTextAndPosition];

    if ([self isOutsideOfScreen])
        return;

   CGPoint currentSpitePosition = [self position];

    floorCharacter = (GameCharacter*)[[self parent]
                                       getChildByTag:kfloorSpriteTagValue];

    CGRect floorBoudingBox = [floorCharacter adjustedBoundingBox];
    CGRect ballBoundingBox = [self adjustedBoundingBox];

    CGPoint floorPosition = [floorCharacter position];


    *Below is where I have added screenSize*
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    isfloorWithinBoundingBox =
    CGRectIntersectsRect(floorBoudingBox, ballBoundingBox) ?
    YES : NO;

    if ((characterState == kStateTravelling) && (isfloorWithinBoundingBox == YES)) {{

                [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint2];
    }

        return;
    }

    if ((characterState == kStateTravellingPoint2)&&(isfloorWithinBoundingBox == YES) && (floorPosition.x > screenSize.width*0.32f) && (floorPosition.x < screenSize.width*0.45f)) {{

                [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint3];  
    }

        return;
    }

    if ((characterState == kStateTravellingPoint3)&&(isfloorWithinBoundingBox == YES) && (floorPosition.x > screenSize.width*0.45f) && (floorPosition.x < screenSize.width*0.55f)) {{

        [self changeState:kStateTravellingPoint4];
    }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I do apologise but I thought I had deleted the first post I made about the above. Also I got the above to work (although not 100% how) so I answered my question with what I had done to get it to work but also added a question with the answer. I am now guessing this is not allowed so I apologise once again. Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Comment: You should reply your own question with an answer. You won't get any score for that, but it may help others having the same problem. Plus people will know that question was answered.

Comment: Hi Divanov, I did but Brad Larson deleted my answer and added it to the question above as I had asked another question in the answer.

Comment: about half way down you will see the following... 'Right I have got the above to work but do not completely understand how I have done it!'   and then I have left the working code under that. sorry for the confusion but new to this site and programming so did not know about not asking another question in an answer (common sense left me for a moment!).

Comment: Yes, your answer is more like follow up question. In such a case it's the better to edit original question.